# How to write single query instead of using loop in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I would like to write a query based on some conditions as shown below. Could you please help me out in this regard?

> ```
> RecordID          MergeRecordID   Status          StatusTime
> 3700432           289015          Invoiced        25-May-09
> 3700433           289015          Invoiced        25-May-09
> 3700434           289015          Invoiced        08-Dec-09
> 3700435           289015          Error           08-Dec-09
> ```

I have a table called `billingValues_tbl` where RecordID is primary key. Please note that MergeRecordID contains mutiple Record IDs.

Step 1: I would like to sort based on MergeRecordID. In above example we will get 4 records.

Step2: All records should have the Status `Invoiced`. If the value in column Stattus is other than 'Invoiced', I should skip that mergerecordid i.e. I should not take this Record into consideration. Then I will go for another mergerecordid/recordids combination. I have written query as shown below but its not giving me desired results.

```
 SELECT RECORDID,MERGERECORDID,STATUS,STATUSTIME

 FROM BE242.BILLINGVALUES_TBL BV1

 WHERE BV1.MERGERECORDID IN ( SELECT BV2.MERGERECORDID

                                  FROM BILLINGVALUES_TBL BV2

                                  WHERE BV2.RECORDID = BV1.RECORDID

                                    AND BV2.MERGERECORDID = BV1.MERGERECORDID

                                    AND BV2.STATUS IN ('Invoiced', 'Cancelled') )

 ORDER BY BV1.MERGERECORDID  DESC;
```

Please any one help me out as soon as possible?

Answer (score 0):

for me it looks like your selecting the table twice although it isn't necessary in this scenario.

if you just want to have all record which have Status equal to Invoiced or Cancelled, than a simple

```
 SELECT RECORDID,MERGERECORDID,STATUS,STATUSTIME
   from BILLINGVALUES_TBL
  where STATUS IN ('Invoiced', 'Cancelled')
```

should do it.

Otherwise, try to check the status not only in inner select, also check it in surrounding select.

Comment: Thanks Dom! I have got the desired results... Thanks once again!